# How can I enable low power mode permanently on iOS?

Tags: ios

I am tired of my phone running out of batteries. This would not happen as much if the phone was always on low power mode. When I charge my phone to 80% Low Power mode is auto disabled. Regarding functionality, I cannot even tell the difference between Low Power mode and not having low power mode, except battery life, so *not* having low power mode on is just a dead weight on battery life. I can still make/receive calls/texts just fine.

How to disable auto-disabling Low Power mode? How can I permanently enable Low Power mode in a way that will not be auto disabled every charge?

Comment: If your phone is running out of battery frequently, then the battery probably need replacing. Apple's fee is very reasonable, and that should give your phone another 3 years of life or so.

Answer (score 2):

There's no direct setting to do this, but you can create an automation in the Shortcuts app on your iPhone that will enable low-power mode when it gets disabled.

To do this, go to *Shortcuts → Automations* and tap "*Create Personal Automation*".

Then choose the "*Low Power Mode*" parameter and select "*Is turned off*". Tap *Next*.

Now, click "*Add Action*" and select "*Set Low Power Mode*". Then set the parameters to "`Turn` Low Power Mode `On`" and click "Next".

Make sure "Ask before running" is disabled to avoid being asked to confirm every time this automation runs.

[image: Screenshot taken on iPhone of the above-described automation with "action" and "Done" screens]