iPhone Podcasts app crashes when Low Power Mode deactivates
The Apple Podcasts app for iPhone is one of the buggiest pieces of software I've ever used. It crashes frequently, often failing to remember the last played content (instead it brings up something much older), so I can't easily resume listening.
Of all the bugs, there is one that occurs predictably: The deactivation of Low Power Mode causes the app to crash. So when the iPhone is plugged in and charging, there will come a point when an 80% charge is reached, triggering the deactivation of Low Power Mode, and in turn a crash of the Podcasts app.
The correlation is clear due to the notification:

Low Power Mode turned off
Battery sufficiently charged.

Having Low Power Mode enabled improves the app's performance, in the sense that crashes occur less frequently. But when charging it's only a matter of time before 80% is reached. Freeing up storage space also reduces the frequency of crashes, but does not prevent crashes triggered by the Low Power Mode bug.
I am wondering:

Have others experienced this with Podcasts or other apps?
Is there a way to prevent Low Power Mode from automatically deactivating?



I personally haven't, 2. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/460575/489896


What version of iOS and what iPhone are you using?
